# Is there a way to put several PictureBoxes in a class or in any other way to hide all of them if a button is pressed?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form in visual studio 2022 (vb.net) that contains several different PictureBoxes
and different RadioButtons that brings up different texts depending what RadioButton is checked.
If i press a certain text a picture that is connected to the text pops up.

I want to hide all PictureBoxes (or make it `.visible = false`) if another RadioButton is checked
without having to manually type in all the PictureBoxes in all the different RadioButtons etc.
Is there a way to "group" 10 PictureBox names into 1 line of code?

For example, instead of typing:

```
Private Sub rblcd_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rblcd.CheckedChanged

    If rblcd.Checked Then
        lblart.Text = ""

        pb25p.Visible = False
        pb45p.Visible = False
        pbJST8.Visible = False
        pbjst15.Visible = False
        pbflexffc8.Visible = False
        pbevio.Visible = False
        pbevroevfs.Visible = False
        pblcd.Visible = False
        pbEVEL3.Visible = False
        pbEVLC.Visible = False
        pbEVFS.Visible = False
        pbEVRO.Visible = False
        pbLEGP.Visible = False
        pbLEBW.Visible = False
        pbLECO.Visible = False
        pbLEIF.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to be able to type (if possible):

```
if rblcd_checked then pbgroup1.visible = false
```

same for textboxes

Have not tried anything because i have no ide how to do it.

Comment: Add all PictureBox Controls that *belong to a group* to a single Container (Panel, GroupBox, whatever) and hide the Container?

Comment: I tried that almost immediately after I posted this.
And yes, that works but its almost the same amount of code to hide everything and also to "sendtoback" and "bringtofront" etc. Im very new to coding so all input/tips is very much appreciated! So thank you very much for the tip :)

Comment: *"its almost the same amount of code to hide"*. If you think that then you obviously didn't do what was suggested. If all those `PictureBoxes` are on the same `Panel` then hiding them all is one line of code, to call `Hide` or set `Visible` to `False` on the `Panel`.

Comment: Are all those `PictureBoxes` in the same place or are they in different places about the form? If they are all in the same place then you're doing it wrong to start with. In that case, you should only have one `PictureBox` and be setting its `Image` property to change what's displayed. In that case, you just set the `Image` to `Nothing` to "hide" all images.

Comment: Yes all pictureboxes as in the same place. Oh, had no clue you could do that! Do you have any example how to put that into code? For example, if I have 3 pictures and 3 textboxes called 1, 2 and 3. And I press txtbox1 then picturebox show picture 1 etc

Comment: Nvm! I figured it out how to do it. Thank u all for the tips and so on! :D